# Is it possible to choose the effect for a switchClass jQuery UI function?

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-ui

I would like to add a subtle and quick fadeOut and FadeIn effect to a button change through switchClass.

`jQuery("a#btnPause").switchClass(pauseClass,playClass,200);`

The effect used by default is a slideLeft.

If I would use standard jQuery, I would like to put an effect on addClass and removeClass, but is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like

```
$("a#btnPause").fadeOut(200).switchClass(pauseClass,playClass,200).fadeIn(200);
```

what you're looking for?

Comment: ah, can you just chain up the effects, that's nice. the a#btnPause is a button, I think it will not be good to have it dissapear, since then the other buttons (which are also there) would move. 
Still I think your solution is great when I fadeout to opacity 0.01.

thanks!

Comment: I don't think fadeOut will cause the surrounding elements to shift because it's only setting the opacity to zero - it's not actually hiding the element (via `display: hide`). Is this correct?

Comment: I thought a fadeout ends with a display:none
I'm gonna do some tests :)

Comment: You're entirely right! I missed that in the docs the first time through. Sorry! On the other hand, you can still fadeTo 0 (rather than 0.01) which won't hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnDemo').click(function () {
                $('a#btnPause').fadeOut(200).switchClass('pauseClass', 'playClass', 200).fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .pauseClass
        {
            color: Red;
        }

        .playClass
        {
            color: Green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="btnPause" class="pauseClass">Text</a>
    <input type="button" id="btnDemo" value="Demo" />
</body>
</html>
```